# Beamer with XeLaTeX on TexLive2013: enumerate numbers in black

Tags: beamer, xetex, color, texlive, enumerate

Using TeX Live 2013, with this combination:

- Beamer (version 3.26) Copenhagen theme.
- Compiled with XeLaTeX.
- Using enumerate environment.

I get the numbers (usally as white font inside blue circle) with black font colour.

With TeX Live 2012, the numbers are white, as expected.

For example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item num
    \item num
    \item num
    \item num
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces with TexLive2012:

[image]

And with TexLive2013:

[image]

What can be done to get the numbers white again? (I want them like that because of the better contrast with the blue background).

---

**Update:**

As requested by @JosephWright, this is the relevant file listing:

```
beamer.cls    2013/01/04 3.26 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision e81e0c94bcc6)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/01/04 (rcs-revision 9a97a4eee358)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2012/04/15 (rcs-revision cc6557182d97)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2012/09/19  (rcs-revision 733629cd0c6c)
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
beamerbasemisc.sty    2012/02/24  (rcs-revision 2ff5461be705)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2012/11/11  (rcs-revision 6afbc49b1109)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/01/04  (rcs-revision 54309ceef997)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2012/12/26  (rcs-revision 1443917db2cf)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2012/09/13  (rcs-revision dcd846607320)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2012/10/02  (rcs-revision 5ed0f4010e8a)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2012/11/13  (rcs-revision ddfba79dac19)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2012/04/03  (rcs-revision 42a0f21a412d)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
```

Comment: Can you add the _precise_ `beamer` version you are using? The easiest way is to add `\listfiles` to your input, run LaTeX and find the `File list` in the log.

Comment: I can confirm the issue; loading `fontspec` doesn't solve it. I have a more recent `beamer` release, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple hack to get enumerate balls drawn with the color set by us or the theme itself.

This solution means to define again the `beamer template` for `enumerate item`, but asking to use the foreground color for `item projected` just when printing the itemize number (not at the beginning of the definition, as has been the case up until now):

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}
{
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.65ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.75}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0.5pt}}
      \pgftext{\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}\usebeamerfont*{item projected}\insertenumlabel}}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}
{
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.55ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subitem projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.4}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    \pgftext{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subitem projected}%
      \usebeamerfont*{subitem projected}%
      \insertsubenumlabel}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}
{
  \begin{pgfpicture}{-1ex}{-0.55ex}{1ex}{1ex}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubitem projected}
    {\pgftransformscale{1.4}\pgftext{\normalsize\pgfuseshading{bigsphere}}}
    \pgftext{%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsubitem projected}%
      \usebeamerfont*{subitem projected}%
      \insertsubsubenumlabel}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
```

Some notes:

1. The only changes are: `\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}` (and their corresponding `subitem` and `subsubitem` when needed) just at the left of `\usebeamerfont*{item projected}`.
2. There must be a reason why using `\usebeamercolor[fg]{item projected}` just as the first command of `pgfpicture` don't work with XeLaTeX and TexLive2013.
3. And surely there could be a simpler workaround, obviously without thinking about hacking the file `texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`.